# Stored Procedure not working in Snowflake

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a Python Worksheet which runs fine,

```
def main(session: snowpark.Session): 
    
    # Establish the Snowpark session with secondary roles  
    session.use_secondary_roles('all')
```

Now when we try to deploy this script, which is now converted to stored procedure It gives us a error **using same role** :

```
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 003001 (42501): SQL access control error:
 
Insufficient privileges to operate on role 'ALL'
 
 in function xxx with handler main
```

We need to use Secondary Role for cross DB Queries, Could someone help me with this.

I tried using Admin role as well yet gives this error.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the entire definition for the stored procedure. Have you tried it with `execute as caller`?

Comment: Thanks! @GregPavlik I was using OWNER, It works with CALLER

Comment: Sorry but I was not able to understand the difference between this 2, If you can put a one line explanation would be greatly appreciated : )

Comment: [Understanding Caller’s Rights and Owner’s Rights Stored Procedures](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/stored-procedure/stored-procedures-rights)